# How to define default for pybind11 function as parameter

Tags: c++, pybind11

As per the pybind [documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/functional.html), we can pass a function from Python to C++ via the following code:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>

int func_arg(const std::function<int(int)> &f) {
    return f(10);
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.def("func_arg", &func_arg);
}
```

How can we define a default function `int -> 1` that is used for *f* if no parameter is passed?

```
$ python
>>> import example
>>> example.func_arg() # should return 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is

```cpp
namespace py = pybind11;

int func_arg(const std::function<int(int)> &f) {
    return f(10);
}

std::function<int(int)> default_func = [](int) -> int { return 1; };

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.def("func_arg", &func_arg, py::arg("f")=default_func);
}
```

An even simpler one is just overload the `func_arg` wrapper itself

```cpp
PYBIND11_MODULE(foo, m) {
    m.def("func_arg", &func_arg);
    m.def("func_arg", [](void) -> int { return 1; });
}
```